# How to get rid of Org-mode link translation?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I write articles with org-mode, It works very well. But I found a very annoying problem.

I post my article to some forum, also I have a lot of pics to post.

I use IMG code to post the pictures.

eg.  [IMG]http://abc.com/a.jpg[/IMG]

I export my org file to ascii or html or anything else formant, Org-mode always make "http" special. It export like this:

[IMG][http://abc.com/a.jpg[/IMG]]

between "http", There are  always a pair of "[". Every time I have to remove this myself.

I wish Org-mode do not handle http string.

Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Org mode actually parses that particular markup poorly (with the square brackets).  If your image links are on a separate line, for example between paragraphs, you can use some markup to disable org formatting:

```
#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
[IMG]http://abc.com/a.jpg[/IMG]
#+END_EXAMPLE
```

A shorthand for this is simply to start the line with a colon followed by a space:

```
: [IMG]http://abc.com/a.jpg[/IMG]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Dillo's answer will save me a lot time to handle such link. BTW, is there other shorthand like ": ".  I want to know which section of manual about it

Comment: Finding this stuff in the manual is actually kind of hard.  This particular section is [11.3](http://orgmode.org/manual/Literal-examples.html#Literal-examples), but other kind of markup are detailed throughout chapter 11.  If you're curious about other command-like syntax, section [15.6](http://orgmode.org/manual/In_002dbuffer-settings.html#In_002dbuffer-settings) covers common #+ settings commands.

Comment: This doesn't work for text in `#+CAPTION:` or `\begin{caption}` environments during LaTeX export, though.